# Where to put Active Support Notification subscribers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I want to use Active Support Instrumentation in refactoring my app. It's a fairly large app and there is going to be a lot of Subscribers.

Where would be the best place to put my Subscriber files?

The obvious place to put them seems to be config/initializers but it doesn't feel right. Especially since my Subscribers would be better orgarnized if split into multiple files.

Any suggestions?